# How can I use asp.net MVC Areas to setup an application to serve my different clients using same code base

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multi-tenant, asp.net-mvc-areas

I am seeking help in setup an application so that I can give my clients their own url for browsing.

I am thinking about creating asp.net MVC application and by using AREAS feature ( I will consider each area as my client) I will develop individual application for my client and provide them the url which will serve a their own application running.

Basically, I want to keep my all clients in one application but give them different url.

As areas works as follows:

- localhost:5699 -- it will land to default home controller and index page
- ocalhost:5699/area1/home/index - it lands to Home controller or Area and renders index view of this area

and so on for another area.

So. I want to ask, can i use this approach to give my clients unique url which I can map to particular Area of application and client can browse simple typing their url and that land to index page of that area?

for example:

- www.area1.com -- I want to map this url to localhost/5699/area1/home/index.aspx
- www.area2.com -- I want to map this url to localhost/5699/area2/home/index.aspx

Please help, how can i will setup all above in production and development environment

Basically, i want to setup my application such that if my client want different UI and additional functionality I can easily alter respective  controller.

Comment: Are you just trying to keep your clients separate so you can track them? Or is each client going to have their own unique controller with their own unique methods?

Comment: Thanks tez.. basically, I am trying to keep some core functionality in my default controller and if i need to modify(override) as per my client requirement i can write that code in respective client controller. You are right.. each client will have their own controller but i want to take advantage of my core methods written in default controller / base controller.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, I think you can accomplish your goal by way of the `Route` and `RoutePrefix` attributes. These attributes will decorate controllers and methods and give you the ability to tweak the URL's exactly how you want it.

**localhost/5699/area1/home/index**

```
[RoutePrefix("area1")]
public class Area1Controller: ApiController
{
    [Route("home/index")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // controller logic here
    }
}
```

**localhost/5699/area2/home/index**

```
[RoutePrefix("area2")]
public class Area2Controller: ApiController
{
    [Route("home/index")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // controller logic here
    }
}
```